# IBM MobileFirst cordova jsonstore plug-in not initializing without extra timeout

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, ionic2, cordova-plugins, jsonstore

I am using  IBM MobileFirst Foundation 8.0, Ionic 2 and typescript for building a Cordova application for iOS and Android.

i have installed `cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore` and `cordova-plugin-mfp` but when trying to initialize a JSONStore collection using below code it is not working. I am getting an error saying JSONStore is  `undefined`.

```
mfpJSONStorageConnector.initGlobalCollections()
```

If I add the same code inside `timeout` as follows I get `WL.JSONStore` as `[object Object]` and `mfpJSONStorageConnector.initGlobalCollections()` is working fine.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 

}, 8000);
```

If i remove settimeout , application will break and `mfpJSONStorageConnector.initGlobalCollections` will not work

eg:

```
constructor(public platform: Platform, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public events: Events, 
    public renderer : Renderer, 
    public mfpJSONStorageConnector: MFPJSONStorageConnector) {

let self = this;

platform.ready().then(() => {
  StatusBar.styleDefault();  

});

self.renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'mfpjsloaded', () => {


          setTimeout(function(){ 

          mfpJSONStorageConnector.initGlobalCollections().then(function(status) {

              authenticationService.getLastLoggedInUser().then((lastLoggedInUser) => {

                   Splashscreen.hide();

              }).catch((ex) => {
                  //Error
              });  
          });  
    }, 8000);

    });
```

**UPDATES**
am using `cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore` not `cordova-plugin-jsonstore`
sorry for the confusion

Comment: Is this the issue on both iOS and Android or only one of the platform?

Comment: both IOS and android

Comment: you should put it within platform.read().then.. plugins get loaded after platform is ready

Comment: @suraj, I have tried same but no changes. but  as per 

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/10/17/integrating-mobilefirst-foundation-8-in-ionic2-based-apps/  --->https://github.com/robpuryear/ionic2/blob/master/myApp/src/app/app.component.ts

we can add mfpjsloaded listener outside the platform ready.

Comment: I see.. since you say it works on timeout.it could possibly be that platform is not loaded...are you using the same version of ionic 2 as the repo ?

Comment: @ArjunTRaj, see suraj's comment.

Comment: i have tried same inside platform.ready and "mfpjsloaded"  even is triggering without any issue.

am using latest version of Ionic2 @IdanAdar 
any dependency on ionic version ?

Comment: No, MFP SDK does not care for Ionic in particular... Ionic itself is based on/requires Cordova and MFP SDK is a Cordova plug-in.

Comment: I don't understand from your comment if your issue is resolved or not. If you were able to get this working, I suggest to write an answer.

Comment: @IdanAdar 

issue is not resolved , i have tried same inside platform.ready , out side also and no change its not working   but  mfpjsloaded event is triggering fine  in both the case also.

Comment: @IdanAdar if i add timeout its working fine but thats not the right solution  as per IBM doc no need of timeout or any other kind of delay .

Comment: It is not a doc, it's just a blog post. The blog post refers only to the MobileFirst SDK (cordova-plugin-mfp) and not to added plug-ins. The blog post refers only to the core SDK and not to added plug-ins. It could be more than possible that additional plug-ins (ANY plug-in, not just MFP) requires additional time to load, in which case allowing the plug-in to load seems like a good thing to do... otherwise thinks will fail. I suggest to look for some Cordova hook for event that will tell you when a plug-in is ready instead of using a timeout value which can be too long or too short...

Comment: Here is another article on handling plugins in Ionic: http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-2-how-to-use-cordova-plugins/

Comment: @ArjunTRaj, please upload to dropbox a sample application with the problem you're facing so we could debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a listener on 'mfpjsonjsloaded'.  That event is fired when the JSONStore plugin completes loading.

```
renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'mfpjsonjsloaded', () => {
  console.log('--> MFP JSONStore API init complete');
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you're using `cordova-plugin-jsonstore`. This is not the same as `cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore`.

`cordova-plugin-jsonstore` is an opened-sourced version of JSONStore that is not compatible with MobileFirst Foundation 8.0. You can read about this incompatible Cordova plug-in, here: https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/jsonstore-cordova/

Instead, you should use the official JSONStore plug-in for MobileFirst Foundation 8.0: `cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore`, as described in the product documentation, here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/jsonstore/cordova/

Comment: sorry for the confusion am using  cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore not cordova-plugin-jsonstore